# Kill -2 or Kill -INT ,how does it kill process

Tags: linux, shell, kill-process

I have two shellscripts:

## a.sh is:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter name": name
echo $name
```

## b.sh is:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=0; i<100; i++))
do
    echo "$i"
    sleep 1s
done
```

then, I start another shell using command `pkill -2 a.sh` `pkill -2 b.sh`
but, the first can be killed
the second cannot be killed,
what does pkill -2 do?

Comment: Remove the loop from `b.sh`, increase the sleep time to a large number and then send the signal again to see what happens. Alternatively, make `a.sh` have a loop. That is, the two examples are not equivalent and comparing their behaviour will not be obvious.

Comment: long sleep can not be interrupted, I don't know why.?

Answer (score 2):

Kill -2 sends an interrupt (2 is the value associated with SIGINT). This will wake up the sleep call but then the loop continues. If you send a 15 (SIGTERM), the process should terminate.

Comment: which type process kill -2 can interrupt

Comment: Any process that doesn't explicitly block it can be interrupted, but may handle the interrupt differently. Some system calls cannot be interrupted, but the interrupt may be handled when that call completes. As suggested by Tom, take a look at the man page for more info.

Comment: `kill -l` should list all signals by number. You can also set [traps](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/trap.1p.html) on all but 9(KILL), and most implementations can `trap` err, exit, and/or debug. `-term` (15) is the default if you don't specify. Do NOT get into the bad habit of using -9 all the damned time... See the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html) for details.